# How to bind HTML component with ng-repeat based on a pre-defined condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

I am very new to AngularJS. I have made an html component which is to be reused across the whole app. Let's say this component gives out the basic info of a product. The basic structure of the HTML is as below:

```
<div class="visible-sm-block">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img class="img-circle img-responsive" alt="Image of product"
                 ng-src="{{}}"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <label>{{ProductName}}</label>
            <p>{{CompanyName}}</p>
            <p>{{ShippedTo}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The product.js file goes as:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('product')
        .directive('productDetails', productDetails);

    /** @ngInject */
    function productDetails() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/productDetails/productDetails.html'
        };
        return directive;
    }

})();
```

The small HTML component would be reused across other HTML pages in the app like this:

```
<product-details></product-details>
```

Now the problem is I cannot bind data with the HTML component when it is used across my pages. The controller for those pages is in a separate folder: app/productshipping/productshipping.controller.js 
I tried using ng-controller="controller_name" in the HTML component itself but no result came. :( Please help.

Comment: do you load the controller? as in angular.module('product', ["your_controller"]);

Comment: you are missing quite a bit to make this work the way you intend.  These kind of directives generally have their own controller, through which they have their own `$scope` object. Also, they generally use an *isolated scope* which allows each instance of the component to show an independent element (`product`, in your case).  there are very good examples of how this works in the official documentation at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: a plunker of the official documentation sample using isolated scope: https://plnkr.co/edit/MIi0qm9Vl2vfzz2mNyDM?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really an interesting question. The code is given below. I am developing an angular framework. So do let me know if you need any further assistance.

Product.js file as follows

```
"use strict";

angular.module("app",[]);

angular.module("app").controller("productController", ['$scope', function ($scope) {


}]);

angular.module("app").directive("tmHtml", function () {
    return {
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            productName: '@',
            companyName: '@',
            shippedTo: '@'
        },
        controller: "productController",
        templateUrl: "/templates/HideShow.html"

    };

});
```

Template HTML file as follows

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="productController">
    <div class="visible-sm-block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img class="img-circle img-responsive" alt="Image of product" ng-src="{{}}" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <label>{{productName}}</label>
                <p>{{companyName}}</p>
                <p>{{shippedTo}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How to reuse this as follows

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/Product.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div>
       <tm-Html product-Name="Sankar" company-Name="Sankar" shipped-To="Sankar">
       </tm-Html>      
   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do take note of the snake cases and camel cases. That is the catch many miss while developing this.

Comment: Do let me know if the above solution helps you Or if am missing something, so that I can edit above solution. Thanks

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for this answer. This is working but I have to bind every single element at a time. Is it possible to pass a whole object to the template HTML from the main page via the directive?

Comment: Sure. Will try to help. Could you please tell me an example of a whole object so that I can adjust the code accordingly

Comment: Please approve the answer by clicking at the tick mark if it is working. Thanks